# Facebook Platform - Verifying Facebook User Access Token in v2.2

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook-graph-api

Question about the upgrade to v2.2 of the Facebook Platform, in particular, this part:

> The previously deprecated REST API has been completely removed in
>   v2.1, and all apps still using it must migrate to using Graph API.

For the most part, in my Android and iOS app I am not using the REST API. I'm using the Android SDK and the iOS SDK. However, I do have one exception. When I call my server to login or really do basically anything, I try to assure that the person trying to login/access data is indeed the person they say they are. I do this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=".$accessToken."&access_token=MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN", false, $context);
$jsonObject = json_decode($response, true);
$data = $jsonObject["data"];
$facebookId = $this->getFacebookId();

 if(isset($data['is_valid']) && $data['is_valid'] === true) {
        if(isset($data['user_id'])) {
               if($data['user_id'] == $facebookId) {
                    return true;
```

A little bit of code missing there, but that's the gist of it. Get an access token and a facebook id. I use the access token to see if it's legitamite and the user_id assigned to that access token is the id of the person trying to get info. If so, I let them in.

My question is, am I understanding correctly that this is going away and I have to use the Graph API to somehow do the same thing? How is this done through the Graph API in PHP given an access token and facebook id from Android/iOS?

EDIT: Just realized this is actually in the 2.0 to 2.1 section, but question still stands, should I be concerned about my server side code?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling the server? Why not just get rid of the middleman and make the call from the device itself? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: @Half Crazed Well there's many other things I'm doing on the server after I do this confirmation logic. This is the only way I know of that I can be sure someone in the middle has not altered the json going over the wire. I do use the device to get an access token, then I send that and the facebook id to the server, confirm again, and then get personal data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking I don't have anything to worry about. The approach I'm using is in the Facebook Platform docs here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#checktoken

Under inspecting access tokens. Nothing on this page talks about it being deprecated.